Why does this Threadpool Deadlock upon Destruction?
I'm trying to understand the new c++20 concurrency features. I use a std::barrier in a threadpool implementation but it deadlocks. What could be the problem with the following threadpool implementation?
The main thread is blocked when the destructor of the threadpool is called. I have a guess why that might be but I am not certain and wonder whether I could rewrite the program slightly and still rely on  a std::barrier
A reproducible example is as follows:
#include <stop_token>
#include <atomic>
#include <barrier>
#include <functional>
#include <stop_token>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>


class ThreadPool {

   public:
    friend void ThreadMain(std::stop_token, ThreadPool*);
    using function = void(void* context, size_t idx);
    explicit ThreadPool(size_t num_threads);
    ~ThreadPool();
    void QueueTask(function*, void* context, int range);

   private:
    std::barrier<std::function<void()>> sync_point;
    std::atomic_flag start{false};
    std::atomic<int> idx{0};
    function* task{nullptr};
    void* ctx{nullptr};
    std::vector<std::jthread> threads;
};

void ThreadMain(std::stop_token stoken, ThreadPool* pool) {
    while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
        pool->start.wait(false);
        if (stoken.stop_requested()) {
            return;
        }
        int i{0};
        while ((i = pool->idx.fetch_sub(1) - 1) > -1) {
            (*(pool->task))(pool->ctx, i);
        }
        pool->sync_point.arrive_and_wait();
    }
}

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(size_t num_threads)
    : sync_point(num_threads, [&]() noexcept { this->start.clear(); }),
      threads(num_threads - 1) {
    for (uint32_t ii = 1; ii < num_threads; ++ii) {
        threads[ii - 1] = std::jthread(ThreadMain, this);
    }
}

void ThreadPool::QueueTask(ThreadPool::function* function, void* context,
                           int r) {
    task = function;
    ctx = context;
    idx.store(r);
    start.test_and_set();
    start.notify_all();
    int i{0};
    while ((i = idx.fetch_sub(1) - 1) > -1) {
        (*(function))(context, i);
    }
    sync_point.arrive_and_wait();
}

ThreadPool::~ThreadPool() {
    start.test_and_set();
    start.notify_all();
    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t.request_stop();
        t.join();
    }
}

void function(void* context, size_t idx) {
    return;
}
int main() {
    ThreadPool pool(2);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        pool.QueueTask(function, nullptr, 100);
    }
}

The example can be compiled with ggc 13.2.0  with the c++20 flag, as follows: g++ main.cpp -O0 -g --std=c++20.
Tasks in the threadpool are added with the QueueTask function. The main thread sets the work and context info for all threads and notifies them of new work. All threads (including the main thread) share the work by picking elements of the task's arguments. When all arguments have been sliced up, they're using a std::barrier for coordination.
When I debug the threadpool with gdb, I see that the program hangs at the threadpool's destructor. With two threads, the main thread waits joining the other thread, while the other thread waits at the barrier:
pool->sync_point.arrive_and_wait(); 

c++reference says about the arrive_and_wait function:

atomically decrements the expected count by 1, then blocks at the synchronization point for the current phase until the phase completion step of the current phase is run. [emphasis mine].

Notably, cppreference does not say that the threads are waiting until the completion function was run I use the completion function to set the start flag again to false. Without that, some threads will continue to pick up work and then wait on the barrier again.
Can I somehow salvage the example above while still using std::barrier and only using minimal modifications?

This is missing a [mcve] that demonstrates the deadlock.  Have you examined your deadlocked program with a debugger though?  Where was each thread blocked?  Have you analyzed how threads got to those lines without your synchronization assumptions being met?

Your destructor might need to call std::barrier::arrive(threads.size())

'Threadpool deadlock', isn't that a movie?

thanks @StephenNewell . I have added  a MWG.

@AndyG. I think this could solve the destructor issue, but other problems with the general implementation would then still remain.

You initialize sync_point with num_threads.  Shouldn't this be num_threads+1, since the main thread waits on the barrier as well as the workers?

The cppreference text could perhaps be clearer, but the standard makes it clear that completion function executes after all the expected number of threads enter arrive_and_wait, and before any of them return.  This includes synchronization in the sense of "strongly happens before".  So using the completion function to clear the start flag should be perfectly correct.

Thanks for your reassurance, @NateEldredge. I looked it up and you refer to "The end of the completion step strongly happens before the returns from all calls that were unblocked by the completion step." (Paragraph 3, https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.barrier#class-3) ? For your comment about the number of threads: I spawn tread - 1 new threads, so I think the expected value of the barrier should be num_threads.

I think I understand the issue now. I should probably call request_stop in each thread before I unblock them with setting start to true. I'll test it tomorrow on the development machine. Thanks for all the comments so far.

There was an error in the destructor with a wrong ordering of events. The desctructor should be written as:
ThreadPool::~ThreadPool() {
    for (auto& t : threads) {
        t.request_stop();
    }
    start.test_and_set();
    start.notify_all();
}

All in all, I've been pretty satisfied with both the conciseness and the performance brought by std::barrier.
